# Simple problem on measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a measurable real
function. I want to show that $\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}\neq \inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(-\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$ or equivalently $\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mid f\mid\leq c \ \text{almost everywhere}\}\neq \inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: -\mid f\mid\leq c \ \text{almost everywhere}\}$.

I thought that I could take the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and choose the constant real function $f(x)=1$. If $\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mid f\mid\leq c \ \text{almost everywhere}\}=1$, then $\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: -\mid f\mid\leq c \ \text{almost everywhere}\}=-1$.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you explain how you came upon this? The quantity on the right-hand side doesn't seem meaningful.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have a the following definition of essential supremum: $\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$, and I was asked to show that ess $\sup (f)=-$ ess $\inf (-f)$, which is false, in my opinion. This equality would work if ess $\sup (f)=\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}: \mu(f>c)=0\}$

Comment: All right.  That's not the standard definition of the essential supremum; generally, the definition is $\text{ess sup}(f) = \inf\{c\in\mathbb{R} : \mu(f > c) = 0\}$ and then we define from that $\|f\|_\infty = \text{ess sup} |f|.$  With the nonstandard definition you mention, your example would be appropriate to show $$\text{ess sup}(f) = -\text{ess inf}(-f)$$ isn't an identity (although this is reason enough to reject that definition)

Comment: I totally agree. This definition was introduced to me by an unreliable source, unfortunately.